# Automating setting instance variables in single purpose controllers that are used by different models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Say I have two models, `Email` and `Message`, with a boolean `read` attribute, and to mark them read I add a `concern` with `mark_read` and `mark_unread` `patch` members that route to `ReadablesController`.

I'd like to make it so that `set_readable` is automatic, not requiring me to manually query the params, and instead just work for all models with a `read` attribute. Is there a simple way to accomplish that?

```
class ReadablesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_readable

  ...

  def mark_read
    @readable.read = true
    @readable.save

    flash[:notice] = "#{@readable.class.to_s} marked read."
    redirect_to :back
  end

  def mark_unread
    @readable.read = false
    @readable.save

    flash[:notice] = "#{@readable.class.to_s} marked unread."
    redirect_to :back
  end

  private

  def set_readable
    throw "error" if params[:email_id].present? && params[:message_id].present?

    @readable = Email.find(params[:email_id]) if params[:email_id].present?
    @readable = Message.find(params[:message_id]) if params[:message_id].present?
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a model has `read` attribute with `has_attribute?(:read)`. From there it is trivial to call your `mark_read` and `mark_unread` methods.

```
@model.mark_read if @model.has_attribute?(:read)
```

This probably goes to your controller's `set_readable` method where it still will have to check a relevant param, say, `params[:read]` to invoke the logic.